# Multiple conditions queries with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I asked this question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com and they wanted me to post it here. I couldn't get this code to work at all. I switched from regular mysql to pdo which is more safer. Could someone tell me what I'm missing here. I've been struggling with it for couple of day, and I could find exact answer when I first searched this site.

```
  $input = $_POST['input'];
 $categories = $_POST['category'];
 $state = $_POST['state'];
 $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode']; 

$qq = $db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM classified  ")or die(print_r($qq->errorInfo(), true));
    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $qq->execute();

    /*** echo number of columns ***/
    $rows = $qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if ($rows>0){
      $query = (" SELECT * FROM classified ");
   $cond = array();
   $params = array();

   if (!empty($input)) {
   $cond[] = "title = ?";
       $params[] = $input;
    }

   if (!empty($categories)) {
    $cond[] = "id_cat = ?";
    $params[] = $categories;
     }

    if (!empty($state)) {
    $cond[] = "id_state = ?";
    $params[] = $state;
    }    

   if (!empty($zipcode)) {
     $cond[] = "zipcode = ?";
     $params[] = $zipcode;
   }

  if (count($cond)) {
  $query .= ' WHERE  ' . implode(' AND ', $cond)or 
  die(print_r($query->errorInfo(),true));
 }

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute($params);
 $ro = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
   }
     if ($ro > 0) {
  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) 
   {
     echo  $row['title'];
   echo  $row['categories'];
   echo  $row['state'];
   echo  $row['zipcode'];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Clean up the whitespace in your example. It'll be easier for everyone reading this to parse, follow and ultimately figure out what the problem is.

Comment: 3 questions: What should it be doing? How is it not working? Do you have error messages to share?

Comment: Looks like you are calling `errorInfo()` on `$query`, which is actually just a SQL string.  Do you have error_reporting enabled? If so, you'll see at least one significant error.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Yes, I have eror report enabled.  I get this error:  PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa\advance_Search.php on line 347, which is $stmt = $db->prepare($query);    but I changed this piece of code:  if (count($cond)) {
  $query .= ' WHERE confirm =0' . implode(' AND ', $cond)or 
  die(print_r($query->errorInfo(),true));
 }. And I get no errors

Comment: Now I tried to echo the query like print_r($query);   and I see: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM classified WHERE confirm = 0 )

Comment: I couldn't answer my own question; I have less <10 reputations:  So I posted an answer, and it worked great, but I'm not sure if I've used any pdo statements : the link http://pastebin.com/xRb4LQEe

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good idea to post an answer here rather than posting a link. I'm sure it will be useful for some people.

```
    $input = $_POST['input'];
    $categories = $_POST['category'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];

    $qq = $db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM classified  ")or die(print_r($qq->errorInfo(),
    true));
    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
    $qq->execute();

/*** echo number of columns ***/
$rows = $qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if ($rows>0){

 $query = " SELECT * FROM classified where confirm='0' ";  
 if(!empty( $_POST['input'])) {

 $query .= "AND title LIKE '%".$input."%' ";
 }


if (!empty($_POST['category']) )
   {
  $query .= "AND id_cat = ".$categories." ";

 }

  if (!empty($_POST['state']) )
  {
  $query .= "AND id_state = ".$state." ";

  }


  if(!empty($_POST['zipcode'])) {

  $query .= "AND zipcode = ".$zipcode." ";
  }
   $query .= "ORDER BY date ";

    }

   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute($params);
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
 //  $ro = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  // it didn't work when I tried to count rows
 if ($result > 0) {
foreach ($result as $row)
 {
 echo  $row['title'];
 echo  $row['categories'];
 echo  $row['state'];
 echo  $row['zipcode'];
 }
 }else{
 echo " No data available";
   }
```